# How to init an object with stubbed values with OCMock

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

Ho do I stub a method used in the init method?

The related methods in my class:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        if (self.adConfigurationType == AdConfigurationTypeDouble) {
             [self configureForDoubleConfiguration];
        }
        else {
            [self configureForSingleConfiguration];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (AdConfigurationType)adConfigurationType
{
    if (adConfigurationType == NSNotFound) {
        if ((random()%2)==1) {
            adConfigurationType = AdConfigurationTypeSingle;
        }
        else {
            adConfigurationType = AdConfigurationTypeDouble;
        }
    }
    return adConfigurationType;
}
```

My test:

```
- (void)testDoubleConfigurationLayout
{
    id mockController = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[AdViewController class]];
    AdConfigurationType type = AdConfigurationTypeDouble;
    [[[mockController stub] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE(type)] adConfigurationType];

    id controller = [mockController init];

    STAssertNotNil([controller smallAdRight], @"Expected a value here");
    STAssertNotNil([controller smallAdRight], @"Expected a value here");
    STAssertNil([controller largeAd], @"Expected nil here");
}
```

My result:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'OCMockObject[AdViewController]: unexpected method invoked: smallAdRight '

So how will I access the AdViewController in the OCMockObject?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use the `mockForClass:` method you will need to provided stubbed implementations for each and every method that are called in the mocked class. including your call into it with [controller smallAdRight] in your first test.

Instead you can use the `niceMockForClass:` method which will just ignore any messages which are not mocked.

Another alternative is to instantiate your `AdViewController` and then create a partial mock for it using the `partialMockForObject:` method. This way the internals of the controller class will do the main part of the work.

Just a though... are you trying to test the AdViewController or a class which uses it? It appears that you are trying to mock the entire class and then test if it still behaves normally. If you want to test that `AdViewController` behaves as expected when certain values are injected then your best option is most likely the `partialMockForObject:` method:

```
- (void)testDoubleConfigurationLayout {     
  AdViewController *controller = [AdViewController alloc];
  id mock = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:controller];
  AdConfigurationType type = AdConfigurationTypeDouble;
  [[[mock stub] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE(type)] adConfigurationType];

  // You'll want to call init after the object have been stubbed
  [controller init]

  STAssertNotNil([controller smallAdRight], @"Expected a value here");
  STAssertNotNil([controller smallAdRight], @"Expected a value here");
  STAssertNil([controller largeAd], @"Expected nil here");
}
```

Comment: Made two small edits to Claus' answer, but essentially the proposed test implementation should pass now

Comment: Sometimes your init method does one-time-only configuration, and the path you want to test won't be executed with this approach. This kind of test generally also works if you just call [AdViewController alloc] in the first line.

Comment: Reading your post once again it's now obvious to me that you should not call init until the controller have been mocked. I hadn't noticed the first time that you actually made an implicit call to adConfigurationType through the property. I've edited my post to reflect this better.

Comment: The code above is incorrect.  Calling [controller init] will call the init method on the OCPartialMockObject, not the init method on the controller object.  To correctly call the controller init, use (void)[[(OCPartialMockObject *)controller realObject] init];

Comment: @Eric since the mock is a partial mock, it will forward the init message to the real controller object as it wasn't stubbed or expected.